# Closed-form solution for an integral involving the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of a $N(0,1)$-distributed random variable

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration

Let $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the probability and cumulative density functions, respectively, of a random variable with distribution $\text{N}(0,\,1)$. That is,
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\,\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cdot\pi}}\cdot\text{e}^{-x^2/2}$$
and
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\,\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\phi(u)\,\text{d}u.$$
I was wondering if you could help me to compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{w}\phi(x)\cdot\Phi(a+b\cdot x)\,\text{d}x\mbox{,}$$
where $(a,\,b,\,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $b\neq 0$, please.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How did this integral come up? Do you expect it to have some kind of closed-form solution?

Comment: Hi, @DavidRoberts. This integral is part of an algorithm I am programming in R-software. My purpose is to avoid the use of integrals in R-software because they reduce the efficiency of my algorithm. For this reason, I need to find a closed-form solution for this integral.

Comment: Both Maple and Mathematica fail with it. Wanting is not harmful, harmful not want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral can be found in *D. B. Owen (1980) A table of normal integrals, Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation, 9:4, 389-419*:
[image]

`BvN` denotes the bivariate normal probability function.

Check in R:

```
> a <- 2
> b <- 3
> w <- 5
> f <- function(x) dnorm(x)*pnorm(a+b*x)
> integrate(f, lower=-Inf, upper=w)
0.7364551 with absolute error < 1.3e-06
> 
> rho <- -b/sqrt(1+b^2)
> Sigma <- cbind(c(1,rho),c(rho,1))
> mvtnorm::pmvnorm(upper=c(a/sqrt(1+b^2), w), sigma=Sigma)
[1] 0.7364551
attr(,"error")
[1] 1e-15
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```

Alternatively, you can express this integral with the Owen $T$-function:

```
> library(OwenQ)
> 1/2*(pnorm(a/sqrt(1+b^2))  + pnorm(w) - 2*OwenT(w, (b*w+a)/w) - 2*OwenT(-a/sqrt(1+b^2), (a*b+w*(1+b^2))/a) - (a <= 0))
[1] 0.7364551
```

Benchmark:

```
> library(mvtnorm)
> library(OwenQ)
> library(microbenchmark)
> 
> a <- 2
> b <- 3
> w <- 1
> 
> microbenchmark(
+   integral = integrate(function(x) dnorm(x)*pnorm(a+b*x), lower=-Inf, upper=w),
+   mvtnorm = {rho <- -b/sqrt(1+b^2); pmvnorm(upper=c(a/sqrt(1+b^2), w), sigma=cbind(c(1,rho),c(rho,1)))},
+   OwenT = 1/2*(pnorm(a/sqrt(1+b^2))  + pnorm(w) - 2*OwenT(w, (b*w+a)/w) - 2*OwenT(-a/sqrt(1+b^2), (a*b+w*(1+b^2))/a) - (a <= 0))
+ )
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 integral  80.677  83.5860 116.97275  90.0240  93.0625 2878.062   100  b 
  mvtnorm 320.550 327.0625 339.22625 330.3975 336.0315  595.829   100   c
    OwenT  22.682  24.6360  28.89006  29.2685  31.9955   51.015   100 a
```

Comment: @Student1981 I've just added a speed comparison in my answer. `OwenT` is the way to go.

Comment: These are efficient reductions of the integral to standard libraries.  But I'd say a solution with the bivariate normal CDF or OwenT is not in closed form; I would restrict the term "closed-form" to quantities that can be calculated with at most a single integral of elementary functions.

Comment: I appreciate your observation, @MattF. I believe I did not choose well my words when I wrote "closed-form solution". I will be more careful next time. However, for my purposes, the approach of Stéphane Laurent's answer is good enough.

Comment: FYI, the condition in the OwenT derivation is wrong. It should be `-(a/w<0)` and not `-(a<=0)`.  The conclusion can be derived from 10,010.3 of Owen's paper and using the property $T(u,v) + T(uv,1/v) = \frac{1}{2} (\Phi(u) + \Phi(uv)) - \Phi(u) \Phi(uv) - \frac{1}{2} [v<0]$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known closed-form solution for this integral, though many have asked for it.  However, for the case of $w=\infty$ you can use Geller and Ng (http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf), integral 4.3.13.